# How to save screenshot in loop with increasing number?

Tags: c#

I currently have a program running in a loop like this:

```
else if (cmd == "streams")
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Please enter your monitors resolution");
                    Console.WriteLine("X:");
                    int xres = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
                    Console.WriteLine("Y:");
                    int yres = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
                    Console.WriteLine("Thank you, recording now started. Note that this is still in beta. Close the software to stop recording");
                    Bitmap memoryImage;
                    memoryImage = new Bitmap(xres, yres);
                    Size s = new Size(memoryImage.Width, memoryImage.Height);
                    Graphics memoryGraphics = Graphics.FromImage(memoryImage);
                    for (; ; System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(20) )
                    {
                        //Send spacebar would go here
                        p.Send(green);
                        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(20);
                        p.Send(regular);
                        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(20);
                        memoryGraphics.CopyFromScreen(0, 0, 0, 0, s);
                        string str = "";
                        str = string.Format(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments) +
                        @"\Screenshot.png");
                        memoryImage.Save(str);

                    }

                }
```

The screenshots are being saved as the name "screenshot" everytime it passes through the loop. I want every time the screenshot is taken, for the number to increase by 1, for example, Screenshot_0001, Screenshot_0002. Thanks alot.

Comment: This seems very similar to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51739769/c-sharp-screenshot-flip-flop-not-working

Answer (score 2):

You are nearly there, just change your for loop from:

```
for (; ; System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(20) )
{
    //Send spacebar would go here
    p.Send(green);
    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(20);
    p.Send(regular);
    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(20);
    memoryGraphics.CopyFromScreen(0, 0, 0, 0, s);
    string str = "";
    str = string.Format(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments) +
    @"\Screenshot.png");
    memoryImage.Save(str);

}
```

...to:

```
for (var i = 0; ; i++)   // <----- note 'i'
{
    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(20); // move sleep to here
    //Send spacebar would go here
    p.Send(green);
    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(20);
    p.Send(regular);
    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(20);
    memoryGraphics.CopyFromScreen(0, 0, 0, 0, s);
    string str = "";
    str = string.Format(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments) +
                        $@"\Screenshot{i}.png");  // use 'i' here
    memoryImage.Save(str);

}
```

**Note**: I think you could probably simplify the `string.Format` line a bit.  An exercise for the reader. ;)

As suggested by [John](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3181933/john), by changing `Screenshot{i}.png` to `Screenshot{i:d4}.png` you'll end up with nicer file names of Screenshot0001.png, Screenshot0002.png, Screenshot0003.png, ... instead of Screenshot1.png, Screenshot2.png ...

Comment: What about `{i:d4}`? :)

Comment: @John oooh! Yes nice