# C# Screenshot flip flop not working

Tags: c#

I am trying to do something very specific here; Essentially, what this code does:

```
else if (cmd == "streams")
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Hello, thank you for testing out the streams beta.\nBefore you start, there are some things you should know.\n First off, all screenshots are saved to your documents folder. They are named streams and streams_green.\nTo stop recording, close the software.");
                    Console.WriteLine("Please enter your monitors resolution (RECORD WITH YOUR GAME IN FULLSCREEN WINDOWED)");
                    Console.WriteLine("X:");
                    int xres = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
                    Console.WriteLine("Y:");
                    int yres = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
                    p.Send(maxfps);
                    Console.WriteLine("Thank you, recording now started.");
                    Bitmap memoryImage;
                    memoryImage = new Bitmap(xres, yres);
                    Size s = new Size(memoryImage.Width, memoryImage.Height);
                    Graphics memoryGraphics = Graphics.FromImage(memoryImage);
                    for (var i = 0; ; i++)
                    {
                        memoryGraphics.CopyFromScreen(0, 0, 0, 0, s);
                        string str = "";
                        string str2 = "";
                        str = string.Format(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments) +
                        $@"\streams{i}.png");
                        str2 = string.Format(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments) +
                        $@"\streams_green{i}.png");
                        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(2);
                        //Send spacebar would go here
                        p.Send(green);
                        memoryImage.Save(str);
                        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1);
                        p.Send(regular);
                        memoryImage.Save(str2);
                        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1);

                    }
```

Is send a dvar to a game, take a screenshot, and another dvar, then take another screenshot ect. As you can see by "p.Send(green)" and (regular). However, I have an issue. I am trying to have this save all of the greenscreen screenshots as streams_green, and the regular ones under streams. It is currently properly saving all of the files, however, the _green images are identical to the regular ones, even though the moment the green screenshot was taken was a completely different displayed frame as the one before it. Thanks.

Comment: For those who wonder, "Dvar was an anonymous virtual band from Russia that played darkwave and electronic music" and "Electroconvulsive therapy (ECT), formerly known as electroshock therapy, and often referred to as shock treatment, is a psychiatric treatment in which seizures are electrically induced in patients to provide relief from mental disorders."

Comment: You do a screengrab, wait 2 milliseconds, save it, wait another msec and save the same image again

Comment: This seems very similar to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51739074/how-to-save-screenshot-in-loop-with-increasing-number

Comment: @HansKeﬆing Yeah, possible duplicate of "sock puppet", *heh*.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the code your method takes only one screenshoot at line  `memoryGraphics.CopyFromScreen(0, 0, 0, 0, s);` and then save it in two separate files by `memoryImage.Save`. If instance`green` (in line `p.Send(green)`) and instance `regular` (in line `p.Send(regular)`) have information you want to save then you should change them to `Bitmap` and save.